# Regex for VHDL Identifier

Tags: regex, vhdl

I'm trying to parse my VHDL code for some additional checks.

I'm looking for a regular expression that check for corrent identifiers in VHDL. And I'm still fairly new to regex.

it has the following rules:

- may only contain alphabetic letters (A..Z a..z) digits (0..9) and the underline ('_')
- must start with and alphabetic letter
- may not end with an underline characters
- may not include two successive underline characters

So my current problem is to check for the two successive underline characters...

Update: I guess I just answered the question myself... please double check

```
[A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9])*
```

Comment: That covers basic identifiers.  But VHDL also supports extended identifiers, enclosed by backslashes, which can contain any graphic ISO Latin-1 character (including backslashes if doubled).

Comment: @sebs, yeah, you're right, I removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!.*__)[a-zA-Z][\w]*[^_]
```

This should do the trick.

**Explanation :**

```
 # (?!.*__)[a-zA-Z][\w]*[^_]
# 
# Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!.*__)»
#    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
#    Match the characters “__” literally «__»
# Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z]»
#    A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
#    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
# Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «[\w]*»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
# Match any character that is NOT a “_” «[^_]»
```

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Identifiers

In your update to the question, you suggest: `{letter}({underscore}?{letter_or_digit})*`. That is exactly what the VHDL specification suggests for the expression. It's also worth noting that basic identifiers are **case insensitive**. That is, `id` and `ID` are treated like they are the same identifier.

### Extended Identifiers

However, in VHDL, there are also extended identifiers. A decent regex for these would be:

```
({backslash}{Any ISO 8859-1 except backslash}*{backslash})+
```

### Reserved Words

Also, note that the following identifiers are not handled traditionally, and are instead reserved words: *This is the list from the year 2002 specification. Depending on the version of the specification that you are implementing, there could be more or fewer reserved words*.

```
abs access after alias all and architecture array assert attribute begin block
body buffer bus case component configuration constant disconnect downto else
elsif end entity exit file for function generate generic group guarded if
impure in inertial inout is label library linkage literal loop map mod nand
new next nor not null of on open or others out package port postponed
procedural procedure process protected pure range record reference register
reject rem report return rol ror select severity shared signal sla sll sra srl
subtype then to transport type unaffected units until use variable wait when
while with xnor xor
```

### Letters

It's also worth noting that in VHDL `[A-Za-z]` are not all of the letters in the alphabet. You should also include the ISO 8859-1 Latin characters. You can find some more information about those characters [here](http://cs.stanford.edu/~miles/iso8859.html#ISO-UPPER).

But, that being said, here are the extra uppercase letters:

```
À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß
```

And here are the extra lowercase letters:

```
à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that better regex is

```
\\([^\\]|\\\\)+\\|[A-Za-z](_?[0-9A-Za-z])*
```

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.2 Character set, 15.4 Identifiers. Since -1993 VHDL upper and lower case letters include those found in ISO/IEC 8859-1.